# Give an example of $f:X\times Y \to Z$ such that $f(a,y)$ and $f(x,b)$ are continuous but $f(x,y)$ is not continuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Give an example of metric spaces $X,Y,Z$ and a function $f:X\times Y \to Z$ such that :

(a)if $a\in X$, then $f(a,y)$ is continuous

(b)if $b\in Y$, then $f(x,b)$ is continuous

(c)$f:X\times Y \to Z$ is not continuous

Actually I think $f$ must be continuous if it satisfies (a) and (b) so I can't construct an example.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be defined by
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},& (x,y)\ne(0,0)\\
0,& (x,y)=(0,0).
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. Now, for each $y\ne 0$ we have $f(0,y)=0$, so $\lim_{y\to 0}f(0,y)=0$, so the map $y\to f(0,y)$ is continuous, and by symmetry the map $x\to f(x,0)$ is continuous. However, considering the line $y=x$, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{2x^2} = \frac12\ne 0,
$$
and hence $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following works:

$f(z)=\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{z^{4}}\right)$ for $z\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Here we are dealing with complex plane.

$f$ is not continuous at $z=0$ because $f(h+ih)=\exp\left(\dfrac{1}{4h^{4}}\right)$ for real $h\ne 0$.

For the separate continuous, we have to consider only for $y=0$, then the function $\varphi(x)=\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{x^{4}}\right)$ for $x\ne 0$, $\varphi(0)=0$ still meets the continuity. Likewise for $x=0$.